# Wordpress admin-ajax.php Loading failed

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a word press plugin for my practice, and in it i am registering a customer by taking some information.

[image]

is_user_logged_in() returns false and then i want to enque script

```
function theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in()){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'frontend-ajax', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ));
        wp_localize_script( 'frontend-ajax', 'frontend_ajax_object',admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ));
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_PHPSidefunction', 'PHPSidefunction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_PHPSidefunctionNopriv', 'PHPSidefunctionNopriv' );
```

and actions from ajax-call code below

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function() {

var $inputemail=document.getElementById('inputemail').value;
var $inputname=document.getElementById('inputname').value;
var $inputlastname=document.getElementById('inputlastname').value;
var $inputpassword=document.getElementById('inputpassword').value;
console.log($inputemail+$inputname+$inputlastname+$inputpassword);
console.log("<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php");
$.ajax({
    url:frontend_ajax_object, 
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "Text",
    data: {
        action: "PHPSidefunctionNopriv",
        inputemail: $inputemail,
        inputname:$inputname,
        inputlastname:$inputlastname,
        inputpassword:$inputpassword
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
    error: function(errortype,textStatus,errorThrown){
        console.log(errortype);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
});
```

and the callback function is here

```
function PHPSidefunctionNopriv(){
//echo 'i am phpside function nopriv';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if($_POST['action'] == 'PHPSidefunction'){
        $email= $_POST['inputemail'];
        $password=$_POST['inputpassword'];
        $userid=wc_create_new_customer($email,$email,$password);
        echo $userid;
        wp_die();
    }
}
}
```

but I'm getting the error while enqueuing script

[image]

Waiting for the help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to load PHP script as javascript file. which is totally wrong.

```
function theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_localize_script( 'frontend-ajax', 'frontend_ajax_object',admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_PHPSidefunction', 'PHPSidefunction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_PHPSidefunctionNopriv', 'PHPSidefunctionNopriv' );
```

User is logged in or not, it doesn't matter. Ajax url will be always `admin_url('admin-ajax.php')` for WP_AJAX.

Comment: Thanks,for reply. but this did not enqueue the script, meanwhile it gives an error like  ReferenceError: frontend_ajax_object is not defined, however it is defined in wp_localize_script( 'frontend-ajax', 'frontend_ajax_object',admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ));

Comment: Brijesh is correct, you are trying to enqueue a php file as js. Try something like this: `wp_enqueue_script( 'frontend-ajax', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/frontend-ajax.js' );` and point it to your js file.

Comment: Thanks @DanielVisser basically, if you look the above code snippet, i want to make an ajax call to,    wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, but this gives me error, 400 bad request.

Comment: So it fixed the script not loading? Can you post the full new error in your question?

Comment: @usamalatif Please refer this link with [example code](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress-a-real-world-example). Your doubt will be clear.